# Downloading the content of "Text" file from skydrive using LiveConnectAPI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, live-connect-sdk

I am downloading a text file from **skydrive** using **LiveConnectAPI** for my **windows phone 7** app

The Text file contains the XML data that i need to write in my **IsolatedStorage**

The Problem is when i download the file from the skydrive and write to the **IsolatedStorage** 
I get **NULL** in the **IsolatedStream**.
I need to write the XML content of the **TextFile** that is in the **skydrive** root folder.

 
Note:-
The File named **userData.txt** is in **"me/skydrive/files"**(Root Folder of skydrive,Please correct me if i am wrong in accessing root folder)

---

```
string id = string.Empty;
>client.GetCompleted += (obj, args) =>
                {
                   List<Object> items = args.Result["data"] as List<Object>;
                    foreach (object item in items)
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, object> file = item as Dictionary<string, object>;
                        if (file["name"].ToString() == "userData.txt")
                        {
                            id = file["id"].ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    client.DownloadAsync(id+"/content");

                };

                client.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files");
```

> When Download Completes

```
client.DownloadCompleted += (o, a) =>
             {
                MemoryStream outputStream = (MemoryStream)a.Result;

//Saving the file to Isolated Storage.

                var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(GlobalConstants.cnst_storefile_name);
                myFileStream.Write(outputStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)outputStream.Length);


                myFileStream.Close();

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(GlobalConstants.cnst_storefile_name, FileMode.Open, myStore));
                string rawData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();

            };

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check which version of the LiveConnect library you are using. Microsoft recently made some breaking changes to SkyDrive and code built with older versions of the library does not work any more. You want version 5.4 of the library.

Comment: Yes that is correct. When i changed the library of LiveConnect to 5.4 the things works perfectly. Other wise the code does not have any problem. Thanks @jrc14